# Systemd cannot run my startup script

Tags: systemd, kali-linux

I've taken a look at every question regarding systemd here and cannot seem to find the answer, so I apologize if I'm somehow missing it.

I just want to run the following script at startup, but it seems it must be after systemd finishes because it is dependent upon the network and gui to be up. I'm trying to set up the mousepad to allow tap-clicking, and trying to run a connect.sh script which connects me to a VPN. The following script does everything it's supposed to do when I run it manually, but I cannot for the life of me figure out why it won't run at startup.

startup.sh:

```
#! /bin/sh
# /root/Scripts/startup.sh

synclient tapbutton1=1 clickfinger2=3 tapbutton2=3
sleep 2
sh /root/Scripts/connect.sh
sleep 10
```

contents of connect.sh:

```
#! /bin/sh
# /root/Scripts/connect.sh


echo "disabling wifi adapter..\n"
ifconfig wlan0 down
sleep 3
macchanger -r wlan0
echo "enabling wifi adapter..\n"
ifconfig wlan0 up
sleep 3
echo "connecting to VPN..\n"
nmcli con up id vpnconnection1
sleep 3
ifconfig
echo "finished\n"
```

/etc/systemd/system/mystartup.service:

```
[Unit]
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/root/Scripts/startup.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I run `systemctl enable mystartup.service` and reboot, but the script clearly hasn't run since the changes have not taken effect.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I updated the scripts to reflect the absolute paths to the script locations. ran `systemctl` and rebooted, but still not working.

For more clarification, I just want to run these two scripts at startup. Registering them as a service doesn't make sense to me, but everything I've researched has brought me here. That said, `systemctl --state=failed` doesn't show mystartup.service listed, and `service mystartup.service status` says `Unit mystartup.service.service could not be found.`

Comment: maybe change WantedBy=default.target to WantedBy=multi-user.target ?

Comment: _[Tell us the error messages](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/problem-report-standard-litany.html)_.  Show us what the logs say about the service.  Prove to us, _with service status and log output_ [edit]ed into the question, that the service has not run.

Comment: Ok, the systemd log says it is definitely running, but getting `Failed to connect to X Server` and the connect.sh script runs but doesn't do what it's supposed to do, so this doesn't solve my problem. As I said above, the script needs to run at the very end of the systemd startup. I will open a new question, thank you.

Comment: Debian or Kali-Linux ?

Comment: @Kiwy Kali is Debian.

Comment: @nohupt no certainly not. `Based on Debian` do not mean is Debian, or there would be no interest in doing a fork of a distro.

Comment: @Kiwy does Debian not have shell scripting or systemd? Not convinced my question is specific to Kali...

Comment: If it has nothing to do with Debian nor Kali just use the correct tag. The fact is Kali is heavilly customized by there developers and side effects could happen. Anyway Kali is not meant to be a daily OS you install on your computer.

Comment: I really don't care what you think I'm using it for, I'm just trying to solve this problem. I'm on Kali and the functionality I'm using is from its Debian core, so I tagged both. Not a crazy concept.

Comment: @nohup I don't judge, I just advise you not to do what you're doing as it's not the goal of the OS. If you like to make your life harder, there's no problem about. My problem was with your tagging. Tag are useful and should be use correctly.  `systemd` is not a core feature of Debian it is backed up by Red Hat from the beginning and was at first implement in RHEL.

Comment: your question inspires me this question/answer, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450835/how-to-execute-command-before-user-login-on-linux I think it's better in your case to limit your script to the display manager more than systemd.

Answer (score 1):

These don't really belong as systemd services...

Setting up the mousepad depends on X running and needs to be done for that session.

The proper way to set that up is to configure that as part of the X config.

See [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#Frequently_used_options) for a way to configure that.

Regarding connecting to the VPN, you should probably configure that in NetworkManager, which controls your connections and knows when your network is up.

See [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager#Use_dispatcher_to_connect_to_a_VPN_after_a_network_connection_is_established) for a way to hook up a dispatcher script to NetworkManager that can bring the VPN up when the network is up.

Comment: it looks like the touchpad was fixed with one of the latest updates to Kali.  However, the dispatcher script you offered for VPN on network up does not work :(